# WAMP virtual host AllowOverrides All throwing 500 error

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost

I have a virtual host set up perfectly on WAMP like so...

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:\Work\BOT\public"
    ServerAlias bot.dev
    ServerName bot.dev
    <Directory "D:\Work\BOT\public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm running a Zend Framework application on bot.dev, so I need to AllowOverrides for the urls to work.  However, when I change `AllowOrverride` to `All` I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

I will be sendint out some major good will vibes to anyone who can  help me with this.

UPDATE:

I opened up the server log and found the following error...

```
D:/Work/BOT/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

So the problem must be in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Not sure what yet.

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer and mark the question as solved by validating your own answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=260159.0

> enable the Apache module called mod_rewrite.
>
> To do this left click WAMP tray icon and select Apache > Modules >
>   rewrite module